# GitHub: External link to my pull requests

Tags: github

I wonder if I can have some external link to share list of all my GitHub pull requests? https://github.com/pulls page is nice but what if I want to show it to someone else? For instance, I want to mention it in my CV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show your pull requests to anyone by adding query parameters to https://github.com/pulls

This [help article](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-issues-and-pull-requests/) gives details of the various options you can filter with.

For your use, you would require the **author:username** parameter. Example

https://github.com/pulls?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=author%3AAskePit+

Answer (score 1):

You can search with `author:{name}` and share this url. For example, to see all pull requests by GitHub user Amislav: https://github.com/pulls?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Apr+author%3Amislav